# add a column with increasing value for each csv line (php)

Tags: php, csv, row, line

i have a csv file with values, 
i want to add a column ID with an increasing number for each row.

I see this page: [http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp]

in this case i have an array defined but i want first count the row of the csv, than for each row add a column with a value. 
Anybody can suggest me a way?

Comment: where you exactly want to add column ID at last or at first ??

Comment: Use a auto increment column.

Comment: at the last, i know i have to use an autoincrement, but i don't know to write inside a php code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$list = array
(
"Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
"Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
);

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
$i = 0;
foreach ($list as $line)
{
  $newline = $line . "," . $i;
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$newline));
  $i++;
}

fclose($file); ?>
```

Comment: okay, assume that $list, is given by an existing csv how i suppose to do?

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: ok, now i have this code:
define('CSV_PATH','IN/');
// path where your CSV file is located
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "AnagraficaArticoli.csv"; // nome del file CSV
 
  $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'w');
  $i = 0;
   foreach($csv_file as $line){
    $newline = $line . "," . $i;
      fputcsv($file,explode(',',$newline));
      $i++;
   } 
but it gives me:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...on line 14